# Warning on pack() in the push notifications script

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pack

I'm writing my push notifications script in PHP.
the `$deviceToken` is correct, but I've a warning in this line:

```
$b = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken));
```

the warning is this:

> Warning: pack() [function.pack]: Type H: illegal hex digit in /myurl.com/send_push_notification.php on line 33

And the notification doesn't arrive.

Do you know why?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` (although I guess this is a copy/paste error since it wouldn't parse) and also, what do you get when you `echo str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken);`?

Comment: yes sorry, it was a copy&paste mistake... of course, in the php script there is the )

Comment: What's the value of $deviceToken? If it's got `123ABCZ`, then the `Z` would trigger the illegal hex digit warning. Z would be anything, even a linebreak/carriage return.

Comment: Also, if it starts with `0x` it won't work (annoyingly)

Comment: the $deviceToken is something like "a9e3a660924c2bf96b6540fe78697bed9fe85332e44323cbe4dbd6b04120eaaf"

Comment: Where does the `str_replace` come from? Where do the extra spaces you are replacing come from? Are you sure they are spaces and not tabs, or some other whitespace character?

Comment: SOLVED! I'm sorry, there was an '\n' at the end of $deviceToken. Now it works! sorry...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I ended up using

```
trim($device_token)
```

instead of

```
str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)
```

Fixed the issue in the end.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. A whitespace is at the back of device token.

Comment: while i am using `trim($device_token)` instead of `str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)`,push notifications are not arriving to iphone devices

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Finally, I found that there was a space character in my URL!
So, just check your URL, perhaps that's the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from the same problem. It solved my issue. try using below code:

```
chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $item[0])) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, try

```
$deviceToken = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', sprintf('%u', CRC32($deviceToken))));
```